# Javascript claims object is undefined when it's been checked?

Tags: javascript

I'm having quite the strange error happen on a fairly simple javascript code. Mainly the code is claiming certain properties are undefined when it's clearly used them beforehand. I'll provide two quick examples :

[image]

this function takes an array of objects and returns the html for a dropdown. The stop variable had been assigned to the length of the incoming array, an error is thrown on the definition line. The bizzare thing is the line directly after it; console.log("DO I HAVE A LENGTH?"+stop) goes through just fine. I was able to workaround this with the commented if (arr) code. Unfortunately the error moves back to here :

[image]

As you can see by the poorly drawn mspaint arrow, The property javascript is claiming to be  undefined is checked earlier in the code. Any ideas on what could possibly be going on, this has been driving me nuts!

Please and Thanks for your help!

Comment: What happens if you set a breakpoint on that line, instead of "checking" with custom code?

Comment: can you provide us with a fiddle?

Comment: `this function takes an array of objects and returns the html for a dropdown.` Well, clearly the problem is that you are not passing in an array of objects. How about including the code where you call it? Preferably not as an image!

Comment: column_model[a]["linked_data"] is indeed an array of objects, I have checked it before it gets assigned to dropdowndata

Comment: @bug56 however ... what exactly is "a"?  Could it be that its value is changing elsewhere?  Why, yes!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The second problem is that your variables "a" and "b" need to be declared with `var` in both of those functions.

It's probably the first problem too.

Because you're not declaring them, that means that both functions are affecting the global variables "a" and "b", essentially messing each other up.

A very good habit to develop is to type

```
"use strict";
```

when you start any new file of JavaScript code. In this case, that would have made those references to "a" and "b" throw errors. Just put

```
var a, b;
```

in both functions.

Comment: oh my god I'm such a dummy.. Don't know why I haven't considered this...

I must have misunderstood how scoping works in JS. I thought that unless I defined a variable outside of all loops/functions/etc that it was non global and confined to that scope ie:

`for(a=0;a<foo.length;a++)
{
 ...a is local
}
var a;
for(a=0;a<foo.length;a++)
{
 ...a is global?
}`

Comment: @bug56 in JavaScript `for` loops etc. do not establish any sort of local scope. Without "strict" mode, if you mention a variable that's not explicitly declared, it's assumed to be global. So long as you use a `var` declaration **inside** the functions, they'll be local to each function (that is, each function will have its own distinct variables "a" and "b", and they won't clobber each other).